# Header files without implementation

Tags: objective-c, class, header-files

I'm working on a open source project, which consist on a framework for iOS devices, and one of the methods is not working as I expected. I tried to search for the implementation of the method, but all I found was a a header file and the method declaration; I didn't find the implementation anywhere. Neither did I find the .m file corresponding to that class.

So I have some questions:

1. How can a class exist without it's implementation and still its methods perform certain operations?
2. What is the purpose of writing this kind of classes.
3. In this kind of situations where should be the methods implemented?

**Note**
The open source project is [FastPdfKit](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit) and the method is [wholeTextForPage:](http://doc.fastpdfkit.com/Classes/MFDocumentManager.html#//api/name/wholeTextForPage%3a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, those methods are somewhere, so it's not that they don't exist, you just can't see them.

Try for example to open UITableView.h, you can see the methods definition, but not the implementation. The implementation is hidden in the library, but you can't see it.

In a nutshell, developers do this to hide the details of the implementation of a class to other users. You just receive a header that tells you which methods you can use, and how, but the details about how are they implemented are hidden for you.

For example, Apple doesn't want you to see how they implemented UITableView, but they want you to know how you can use it.

Here you can find a tutorial about how to create a library for Objective-C:

[Creating Static Libraries for Objective-C](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't know you can hide the implementation of your design in a library. Since many classes are provided, I assumed the implementation of the method was available to the user.

Comment: De nada, I just updated it with a link in case you want to go deeper on that.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Muy buen link.